# Display ajax loading image while uploading image to server

Tags: ajax, file, upload

How can I create a form which uploads an image to the server, but after the form post request is sent, I don't want to wait 20 seconds for the page to load(as the image is uploaded)

How can I just submit the form, and have a uploading.... message displayed while the file is uploaded. How is something like this done?

Something similar to when you are uploading an attachment to an email.. You get a little progress bar(although it doesn't show the true progress) displayed while the file is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like: jQuery BlockUI if it suits your needs:
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/